# Invalid Viewstate with Hack Attempt -1 in String

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, viewstate

Update, the question is: Can I block the form string value of -1' before it hits Global.asax?

So, we get these errors in Global.asax fairly consistently. It is a form based, bot hack attempt that tries to pass invalid form values. The one thing that stays the same is that one of the form values is "-1". If I can block that, then I would be ok. However, I can't block it on the page because Global.asax is getting the error first and causing the page error. How can I check for this string and stop processing?

```
Error Message: System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array. at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

Form Values: 
advsearch:1
keywords:
ctl00$footer1$ddlcurrency:1
ctl00$cpmaincontent$ddlcategory:170
ctl00$cpmaincontent$ddlsubcategory:0
ctl00$cpmaincontent$ddlsortby:0
ctl00$ucfooter$ddlcurrency:1
__viewstate:/...
__eventvalidation:/...
ctl00$footer1$sitepath:1
ctl00$ucheader$hdnsplitedval:1
ctl00$ucheader$txtsearch:1
ctl00$ucheader$btnsearch:search
ctl00$cpmaincontent$txtkeyword:1
ctl00$cpmaincontent$btnsearch:1
ctl00$cpmaincontent$uccolleft$hfcatname:1
ctl00$cpmaincontent$uccolleft$hfsubcatname:0
ctl00$ucfooter$sitepath:-1'<--------
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My apologies if it is not clear. Can I block the form string value of -1' before it hits Global.asax?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? Similar thread (see Error 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205564/my-event-log-is-full-of-viewstate-was-invalid-and-unhandled-exception